# Error in mySQL query pulling from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

My query reads as follows:

```
"SELECT config.*, utinfo.* userinfo.* "."FROM config, utinfo, userinfo "."WHERE config.cxid = utinfo.xid"."AND utinfo.uid = userinfo.id"
```

It was working fine before i added the

```
."AND utinfo.uid = userinfo.id"
```

part at the end.

Easier way to do this? Or something im missing?

Comment: John pinpointed a valid problem. If it's still not working then something is wrong with 'utinfo.uid=userinfo.id'. Maybe the fields have a different name? What is the error returned?

Comment: -1 for not giving us the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A space:

```
"WHERE config.cxid = utinfo.xid "
                               ^ - add space here
```

#### Edit:

Since that alone is not the problem, I'll make an educated guess as to what you're really trying to achieve. It looks to me like you're trying to select all the records in `utinfo` that have a `config` ID, and those that have a `userinfo` ID. An `INNER JOIN` would be the best way to handle this:

```
SELECT *
FROM utinfo
INNER JOIN config ON config.cxid = utinfo.xid
INNER JOIN userinfo ON userinfo.id = utinfo.uid
```

Also, in production environments, I would stay away from `SELECT *` as it could break your application if you add or remove a column in the database.